# Assignment Rule Email Notifications are not sending

Tags: apex

We have the following queue in our organization and when the queue becomes the owner of the case, we want an email to be sent to the queue members.

Below is our current setup with the queue and the assignment rule.

[image]

[image]

How can we have the email go out every time the queue becomes the case owner?

Comment: So did you able to send the email to queue? I am also stuck on same situation.

Comment: @KamranJabbar - There is a release update that you have to enable. It is something along the lines of allowing these rules to reevaluate.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more as I didn't get your point?